# Solr highlighting queries in parentheses

Tags: solr, highlighting

Recently I've deployed Solr 5.2.1 and I've observed the following issue:

My documents have two fields: `id` and `text`. Solr is configured to use `FastVectorHighlighter`. I've created the `schema.xml`, `solrconfig.xml` hasn't been changed in any way.

I have a following highlighting query: `text:((foo AND bar) OR eggs)`. Let's say the documents contains only `bar` and `eggs`. Currently *both* of them are highlighted. However the desired behavior is to highlight `eggs` only since `(foo AND bar)` is not true.

The query I send has following parameters:

```
        'fl': 'id',
        'hl': 'true',
        'hl.requireFieldMatch': 'true',
        'hl.fragListBuilder': 'single',
        'hl.fragsize': '0',
        'hl.fl': 'text',
        'hl.mergeContiguous': 'true',
        'hl.useFastVectorHighlighter': 'true',
        'hl.q': 'text:((foo AND bar) OR eggs)'
```

I'd like to know what should I do to make it work as expected.

Comment: I didn't manage to find a proper solution, however I devised a hack which I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33356271/5419223).